# How to make both bits of code run at the same time

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

Hey everyone i am very new to Arduino and c++ and was struggling with some code and was hoping someone can just tell me whats wrong and i can fix it.

Basically i am trying to get a traffic light and a receiver script to run the same time. Currently what happens is once the light cycle is over it runs the receiver code once and only captures one signal being transmitted. I want it to be constantly ready to receive information from the transmitter.

I have tried creating two seperate functions but it still either doesnt work (no lights) or it does the once a cycle thing

```cpp
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h>

int ledPins[] = {2,3,4};
RH_ASK rf_driver;

void setup() {
  int index;
  for (index = 0; index <= 2; index++) {  // Intilaize ASK object 
    rf_driver.init();
    // Setup Serial Moniter
    Serial.begin(9600);
  }
  {
    pinMode(ledPins[index], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() { /****** LOOP: RUNS CONSTANTLY ******/
  int oneAfterAnotherLoop();
  int RadioController();
} //--(end main loop )---

void oneAfterAnotherLoop() {
  int delayTime = 100;
  digitalWrite(ledPins[0], HIGH);
  delay(4000);
  digitalWrite(ledPins[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPins[1], HIGH);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(ledPins[1], LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPins[2], HIGH);
  delay(4000);
  digitalWrite(ledPins[2], LOW);
}

void RadioController() {
  uint8_t buf[19];
  uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
  if (rf_driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) {
    Serial.print("Message Recived: ");
    Serial.println((char*)buf);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Arduinos are single thread only AFAIK. So you would always have to pause one thing to do the other.

Comment: do not use `delay`.  Do everything in one loop . Check millis for led sequencing. Check not blocking way if there is data available, then read it then parse and if OK print message

Comment: Have a read here https://arduinoplusplus.wordpress.com/2019/07/06/finite-state-machine-programming-basics-part-1/ Also, note that if you have an STM32-based Arduino running **FreeRTOS** you can indeed run multiple theads/tasks. Good luck!

Comment: See other comments, and also, have a look at your setup(); your for loop is a mess and doesn't set all pins to output.